# Showing submenu's block as default when hover over parent menu item

Tags: jquery, css

I want to show the block of first grand-child-menu item's block as a default block when one hovers over the parent menu item.

```
 <ul  class="main-nav">
 <li class="main-menu item first">Parent Menu Item
      <ul  class="sub-child">
        <li class="sub-menu">
          <ul class="grand-child">
             <li class="grand-child leaf first">
                <div>A block</div>
             </li>
             <li  class="grand-child leaf">
                <div>Another block</div>
             </li>
             <li class="grand-child leaf last">
                <div>Yet Another block</div>
             </li> 
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Difficult to understand the requirement. Can you add some image as to what you exactly want.

Comment: [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Excuse me. Blank Fiddle.

Comment: Requirement is when i hover on "Parent Menu Item " then "A block" text should be visible, and when I hove on another menu item then it should display its child div.

Comment: check again pls

Comment: But they are visible anyhow. Do you want those grand `li` to hide initially and then perform your functionality?

Comment: @AakashThakur Currently its not hiding "A Block" when I hover on other grand-child menu item.
Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgzj77g3/2/)

Comment: I can't seem to understand your requirement here. What code do you currently have. Can you share with fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Found you a solution:

Check out this jQuery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('li.main-menu .leaf.first').css('display','none');

  $('li.main-menu').hover(function(){
    $('li.main-menu .leaf.first').fadeIn(500);
  },function(){
    $('li.main-menu .leaf.first').fadeOut(500);
  });

});
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/47hc05mr/4/